# AVPlayerLayer pauses currently playing audio

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a `ViewController` which I add an `AVPlayerLayer` to have a video background. For that I use `AVPlayerLayer` and add it to the view's layer. If I have Spotify or anything else playing audio playing while opening that ViewController the PlayerLayer pauses it.

How can I end this behavior?

I create my layer like this:

```
lazy var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer! = { 
    var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer!
    if let src = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Untitled", ofType: "mp4") {
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: AVPlayer(URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(src)))
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = nil
        playerLayer.opaque = true
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        playerLayer.player?.muted = true

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    return playerLayer
}()
```

As you can see Ive tried with setting the `muted` property to true, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other apps' audio is interrupting yours.

You need to create an [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html) and set the "mix with others" option.

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I did like this: `try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)`

Comment: Thanks! Did I do the wrong swift version? I'll update the answer.

Comment: I was writing my comment before you edited some code to your answer :) yes might be good to update to latest version ;)

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for what to do when your app is doing two things at once? For example, playing a podcast and also wanting to play a muted video?